# I converted my project into swift ver 3.0 and also did pod update, but cannot update WDImagePicker pod

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there any other way that I can update WDImagePicker pod version which is compatible to swift version 3.0?

Comment: show your pod file

Comment: source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 3.0.0'
pod 'OneSignal'
pod 'Device', '~> 3.0.0'

pod 'SwiftOverlays'
pod 'WDImagePicker', :git => 'https://github.com/justwudi/WDImagePicker.git', :tag => '0.2.2'
pod 'CZPicker'
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'



post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end

target "ProjectName" do

end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This project is a swift3 version of WDImagePicker - [enter link description here](https://github.com/soeurngsar/DWImagePicker-Swift3)

Comment: update pod using this link but unable to import pod into a swift project, 
using import WDImagePicker ;

Comment: try cleaning then building before you run the workspace

Comment: I tried the everything you mentioned, but still got error as, import WDImagePicker - No such module'WDImagePicker'